# Typecast do malloc é recomendável?

Tags: c, alocação

Já li a respeito que não é recomendável fazer o *typecast* do `malloc` quando estamos alocando memória para uma nova variável ponteiro, e muito sites e livros ensinam esta prática na alocação de memória, isso me deixou com algumas duvidas.

- Por que não é recomendavél fazer o *typecast* do `malloc`?
- Que tipo de complicações esta pratica pode trazer para o meu
  programa?

Um exemplo **com** e **sem** o *typecast* do `malloc` para ilustrar a situação:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int * v, * x, * z;
    v = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    z = (int) malloc(sizeof(int));
    x = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *v = 10;
    *x = 5;
    *z = 50;

    printf("v=%i\nx=%i\nz=%i", *v, *x, *z);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assim como muitos autores e como está escrito no artigo **[C-faq Malloc Cast](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html)**, todos dizem que o `typecast` em **C**, não é necessário, e devido a tratamento automático de tipos `void *` para outros tipos, então sugerem não fazer a utilização dele, mas há casos em que o *typecast* ainda será necessário.

> Qual a finalidade do *typecast*?

O *typecast* serve apenas para fazer uma pseudo conversão. Isso quer dizer que o valor da variável não é convertido, mas sim mascarado. Ex:

```
char c[] = {244,1,0,0}; // vetor de char com 4 posições
int *n; // ponteiro de inteiro
n = c;

printf("%d\n", *n);
```

> `c` guarda os valores **[244] [1] [0] [0]**.
>
> `c` é um vetor de **4** bytes.
>
> `n` tem o tamanho de **4** bytes assim como `c`

Quando atribuir `c` para `n`, não dará erro, pois o conteúdo para armazenar valores de ambos é o mesmo. O que acontece é que `char *` é diferente de `int *`, e isso gera um alerta indicando isso.

Algumas linguagens como Java e C++ não permitiriam essa atribuição, pois são tipos diferentes. E é ai que entra o *typecast*

```
n = (int *) c;
```

Isso impede que o compilador envie um alertá de tipos diferentes de variáveis. E é exatamente isso que acontece quando se usa o `malloc`. O retorno `void *` está apenas sendo tratado como `int *`, `char *`, ou o qual você esteja usando.

**Conclusão:**

Não é como se o *typecast* não fosse recomendado e nem viável, não é necessário (em certas ocasiões). Usar o *typecast* para passar valores de `float` para `int`, e `unsigned` para `signed` é usado e não usá-lo, pode acabar trazendo problemas para seu código, mas também pode mascarar alguns erros como diferença de tamanho de estruturas e coisas do tipo, mas são alguns problemas causados por descuido do próprio programador.

**Referencias:**

**[c-fac](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html)**

**[Typecast em C SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558837/what-exactly-is-a-type-cast-in-c-c)**

**[Typecast is necessery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359310/is-the-type-cast-necessary-when-using-malloc-in-c)**

**[Pontov](http://www.pontov.com.br/site/cpp/46-conceitos-basicos/80-c-type-casting-1o-parte)**

**[TIExpert](http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/c/typecast.php)**

Answer (score 4):

Realmente não é recomendável realizar o typecast, ao menos em C. O retorno da malloc é em sua essência um ponteiro para void (void*), sendo então implicitamente convertido para outro tipo de ponteiro.

Como complicações, eu digo por experiência própria, a utilização de typecasts em C pode vir a mascarar problemas que o compilador conseguiria, idealmente, identificar.

Mais informações, no C-FAQ http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html

Answer (score 3):

Nao 'e recomendavel fazer o *cast* ao resultado do `malloc()` para o compilador indicar o erro da falta do `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Como o compilador nao tem informacoes sobre o tipo de resultado do `malloc()` ele parte do principio que essa funcao devolve um valor do tipo `int`. Depois

```
v = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

a conversao explícita converte esse `int` (nesta altura ja invocaste UB, pois estas a tratar o valor devolvido como se fosse um tipo diferente que ele efectivamente é) num `int *`. Nota que esta conversao nao é valida, mas como foi um pedido explicito do programador o compilador nao se queixa. Finalmente o novo valor (invalido) de tipo `int *` é atribuido a variavel.

Sem a conversao explicita, o compilador queixar-se-ia da conversao automatica entre `int` (o tipo de valor que ele assume que a funcao `malloc()` devolve) e `int *` --- o que levaria o programador (experiente) a adicionar o *header* correcto.

---

### Mais notas

Sem `#include <stdlib.h>`

```
    int *v, *x, *z;
    v = (int *)malloc(sizeof (int)); /* 1a */
    z = (int)malloc(sizeof (int));   /* 2a */
    x = malloc(sizeof (int));        /* 3a */
```

Com `#include <stdlib.h>`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
/* ... */
    int *v, *x, *z;
    v = (int *)malloc(sizeof (int)); /* 1b */
    z = (int)malloc(sizeof (int));   /* 2b */
    x = malloc(sizeof (int));        /* 3b */
```

---

#### 1a -- **ERRO**

O `malloc()` devolve um valor de tipo `int *` que é assumido como `int` devido à ausência do protótipo correcto. Alem disso, a conversão explícita deste `int` para `int *` não é válida, mas como foi um pedido explícito do programador, o compilador não se queixa.

#### 1b -- Redundância

Como o `malloc()` devolve um valor de tipo `void *`, este valor seria automaticamente convertido para `int *` durante a atribuição a `v` (ponteiros para `void` são compatíveis com ponteiros para qualquer tipo). A redundância não é um erro, mas é desnecessária. *Ninguém escreve `return ((((42)))); /* parenteses redundantes */`*

#### 2a -- Erro e redundância

No primeiro caso temos um valor de tipo `void*` devolvido pelo `malloc()` interpretado como `int` por causa da ausencia do *header* correcto. Depois disso temos a redundancia de pedir a conversao de `int` em `int`. A seguir, a atribuicao dum valor de tipo `int` a variavel de tipo `int *` esta errada, mas o compilador tem de se queixar. Nota que neste caso o erro nao tem nada a ver com o uso que se faz de `malloc()` ou da conversao do resultado. A atribuicao dum `int` a um `int *` esta errada.

#### 2b -- **ERRO**

Tal como em 2a, o erro nao tem a ver com o uso de `malloc()` ou a conversao do valor devolvido.

#### 3a -- **Erro** que o compilador se queixa e facilmente se corrige

Quando o compilador se queixa da atribuicao dum valor de tipo `int` a uma variavel de tipo `int *` (o *gcc* tem um texto que induz em erro para este erro espicifico), o programador repara que lhe faltou a inclusao do header `<stdlib.h>`.

#### 3b -- OK

Maneira correcta de usar `malloc()`.

---

Mais um *tip* (para evitar problemas futuros se o tipo de variavel mudar, por exemplo, de `int capacidade` para `double capacidade`)

```
    int *capacidade;
    /* ... */
    capacidade = malloc(200 * sizeof (int));
    /* ... */
    free(capacidade);
```

A certa altura altura alguem se lembra que vai ser necessario ter, por exemplo, 3.14159 de capacidade e decide-se mudar o tipo para `double`. Nestas condicoes vai ser necessario alterar o codigo em 2 locais: na definicao e na alocacao.
Usando o objecto propriamente dito na alocacao, apenas se muda na definicao

```
    double *capacidade;
    /* ... */
    capacidade = malloc(200 * sizeof *capacidade); // usa o tipo do objecto
    /* ... */
    free(capacidade);
```