# char[] ou *char malloc?

Tags: c, array, c++, ponteiro, memória

Qual diferença em C entre

```c
char text[10]
```

ou

```
char *char = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

Qual vantagem de usar malloc em um ponteiro?

Comment: Não a necessidade de fazer o type cast do malloc, veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123208/typecast-do-malloc-%c3%a9-recomend%c3%a1vel).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A principal vantagem é que você não precisa saber do tamanho (no seu caso, 10) a priori. Se você sabe exatamente quanto espaço você precisa quando tiver criando o seu programa, e você só vai usar aquele endereço de memória dentro da função onde a variável é declarada (ver o próximo parágrafo), então usar a primeira sintaxe é mais conveniente (já que você não precisa se preocupar em liberar a memória alocada).

Como `malloc` aloca o espaço no *heap* em vez de na pilha, o valor alocado pode ser válido até mesmo depois que a função onde ela é iniciada termina - na pilha quando a função (escopo) termina, o espaço da pilha é liberado; no *heap* você é responsável por liberar a memória.

Comment: Neste caso `char text[10]` será alocado no **stack** pelo compilador?

Comment: Sim, ou pelo menos você pode assumir que sim. É possível que o compilador tenha alguma otimização no código que ele seja alocado em outro lugar, mas essa otimização não pode ir de encontro às premissas de que o dado é alocado na pilha.

Answer (score 16):

O primeiro aloca 10 posições na memória (provavelmente no *stack*, mas depende do contexto onde está sendo usado) para um tipo `char` que no caso tem tamanho garantido de 1 byte. E esse local de armazenamento será chamado `text`.

O segundo aloca memória no *heap* também para 10 posições do tipo `char` (`sizeof(char)` é desnecessário). A função `malloc()` retornará um ponteiro para o local da memória alocado e esse ponteiro poderá ser armazenado na variável (no caso foi chamada de `char`, mas esse nome é inválido).

O uso do `malloc()` que é armazenado no *heap* permite que o objeto sobreviva mesmo depois da função (ou *stack frame*) acabar. Se fosse alocado no *stack*, ele é destruído no fim do *stack frame* onde foi alocado. Também pode ser um problema para o *stack* se o tamanho a alocar for grande ou não for facilmente determinado como pequeno.

Se não tiver um `free()` em algum lugar provavelmente haverá um vazamento de memória.

Em C++ não é recomendável usar nenhum dos dois.

Leitura complementar:

- [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)
- [Performance de acesso a dados na heap e stack e alocação de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101)
- [Alocação dinâmica de memória X vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120103/101)
- [Diferença entre array de char e ponteiro de char](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130792/101)
- [Quando ocorre o Stack Overflow?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101)
- [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).