# Conversão decimal em binário em linguagem C

Tags: c, conversão, binary, ascii, decimal

O código abaixo, do original (http://www.programasprontos.com/algoritmos-conversores/conversao-decimal-para-binario-c/) "imprime" um número decimal entre **0 e 255** em binário.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
 int n; // Número de entrada
 int r; // Resultado do deslocamento
 int i; // Contador

 printf("Digite o numero: ");
 scanf("%d", &n);

 // Utiliza um número de 32 bits como base para a conversão.
 for(i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Executa a operação shift right até a última posição da direita para cada bit.
    r = n >> i;
     if(r & 1) {
        printf("1");
     } else {
        printf("0");
     }
 }

 printf("\n");

}
```

Preciso fazer a conversão de vários números em decimal (**entre 0 e 255**) p/ binário e posteriormente vice-versa. Assim vejo que seria útil usar a lógica do código acima em uma `função` p/ fazer a conversão, ou até mesmo um `for`enorme (apesar de achar inviável a 2ª opção).

Os vetores:

```
 char *num_corresp_int;
   num_corresp_int = (char *) malloc(tamanho * sizeof(char));
 char *vetor_binario;
   vetor_binario = (char *) malloc(tamanho * sizeof(char)); // cada posicao do vetor_binario
                                                     // so precisara ter 8 bits e nada mais.
```

são alocados dinamicamente. Sendo que o vetor `num_corresp_int` armazena os números em decimal e o vetor `vetor_binario` armazenará sequencialmente os números em binário (dos decimais correspondentes).

Exemplo: se `num_corresp_int[0] = 65` e `num_corresp_int[1] = 66`, o `vetor_binario` da posição `[0]`a `[7]`deverá ter os seguintes números correspondentes da tabela ASCII: `01000001` e, da posição `[8]`a `[15]` os seguintes números: `01000010`. Ou seja, a cada 8 posições do `vetor_binario` teremos juntos a **representação binária** de um número decimal da **tabela ASCII entre 0 e 255**.

Como terei que transformar e armazenar indefinidos números decimais em binário, e depois o contrário também, qual é a melhor solução? Criar uma `função` ou um `for` enorme?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo,

Answer (score 5):

Não há dicotomia entre essas duas coisas. A função existe para isolar e/ou generalizar um algoritmo, o laço serve para repetir coisas.

A não ser que esteja falando em usar iteração ou recursão. Em linguagens imperativas eu sempre opto por [iteração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185497/101) até que a [recursão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101) seja mais adequada.

Duvido que precise armazenar tudo isso em um vetor estático ou dinâmico. Até talvez se fizer uma função que retorne os números e outra que imprima seja melhor.

Se for o caso, o vetor de binário está errado porque se for guardar a representação textual do binário, precisará de 8 bytes em cada posição, está reservando apenas um. Se for guardar o número mesmo e não sua representação, então nem precisa disto tudo. Na verdade se vai até 255 não sei porque precisa de um vetor de `int`. Pior, está tentando reservar um espaço para `char` em um vetor de `int`. Isso será uma maluquice, não dará certo.

Ambos vetores estão armazenando `int`, não está fazendo nem perto do que imagina. Não tem nada de decimal ou binário aí.

## Representação textual

Eu sempre falo, o número é uma coisa, a sua representação textual é outra. O que você vê quando dá um `printf()` é a representação textual. Estamos tão acostumados com ela em decimal que quando vemos isso achamos que é o número, mas não é. O computador não entende isso, essa forma é a que humanos entendem. É um texto.

O enunciado desses exercícios todos já costumam estar errados, porque não se converte números, números são números. O que se converte é a representação textual em decimal para a representação textual em binário, ou melhor ainda, gera a representação textual em binário partindo do número.

Então mesmo que deseja fazer isso, seria mais coerente cada representação ter 8 `char`s no binário e 3 no decimal, se for até 255. Caso contrário está usando coisas diferentes e se valendo do mecanismo próprio do C de converter um número em sua representação textual na hora que precisa.

## Conclusão

Quando resolver esses problemas no entendimento conceitual já entrará no caminho para uma solução correta. Aí terá uma dúvida mais concreta para fazer uma nova pergunta.

Não vejo porque precisaria de um `for` enorme, uma linha resolve.

Um adendo, [não use *cast* no `malloc()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123208/101). Também não use, `sizeof(char)`, que é sempre 1. Não declare todas as variáveis antes. Não declare a variável em uma linha pra atribuir na seguinte. Eu imagino que está pegando exemplos ruins e vai aprender tudo errado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mudei os vetores `num_corresp_int`e `vetor_binario` para `char`, assim cada posição desses vetores vai ter apenas `1 byte`. Vou precisar guardar em cada posição do vetor binário, um `bit`correspondente até que se forme a representação binária desse decimal na tabela **ASCII**.

Comment: Acho que você não leu o que eu escrevi.

Comment: Sim, li sim. No malloc`(sizeof(char)`não mudei nada, pois entendo o que você disse, porém p/ mim, que sou iniciante em programação, fica _mais fácil de visualizar_. Quanto ao `cast` no malloc, estou aprendendo a sempre fazer essa conversão. Como estou fazendo o cast, nesse caso estou sendo redundante? Não sou expert no assunto ainda. Já li o link indicado, e vou ler de novo p/ melhorar o entendimento. E por último, acredito que entendi o que foi apresentado na sua resposta sobre **Representação textual**, tanto é que mudei os tipos dos vetores.

Comment: Mas não leu sobre ter 8 ou 3 caracteres. E a conclusão que ainda não tem um problema específico. Nem deveria editar pra arrumar a prgunta. A pergunta está feita, a resposta foi dita em cima disto, não dá para ir editando a pergunta e  a resposta até chegar no que você quer. O que foi perguntado foi respondido. Quando você tiver um algoritmo mais ou menos pronto, sugiro postar outra pergunta com os problemas mais específicos.

Comment: Se entendi bem, quanto a ter 8 ou 3 caracteres na **Representação textual**, o vetor `num_corresp_int` só armazenará um número entre 0 e 255, que tem somente 8 bits, e assim o faço, pois o algoritmo que transforma o núm armazenado de cada posição do vetor `num_corresp_int` em binario, pegará esse número uma **única** vez. Ou seja, na posição `[1]` terá um número que será transformado em binário, e na posição `[2]` outro que será transformado, e por aí vai. Por isso opto por deixar cada número representando em uma única posição no vetor `num_corresp_int`.

Comment: Alguém já deu a solução pronta pra você, nem precisa pensar mais sobre isso.

Answer (score 2):

**DECIMAL PARA BINÁRIO**

**Algoritmo:**

[image: metodo]

**Implementação:**

```
#define swap( a, b )   do{ int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; }while(0)

const char * dec2bin( char * bin, int d )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for( i = 0; d > 0; d /= 2, i++ )
        bin[i] = (d % 2) ? '1' : '0';

    for( j = 0; j < (i / 2); j++ )
        swap( bin[j], bin[ i - j - 1 ] );

    bin[i] = '\0';

    return bin;
}
```

**Explicação:**

O primeiro `for` faz com que o decimal `d` seja dividido por 2 até que o resultado dessa divisão atinja zero. O resto ou módulo de cada uma dessas divisões (que só pode ser '1' ou '0') é concatenado na string `bin`.

A montagem do valor em binário acontece a partir do bit mais significativo (`MSB`) para o menos significativo (`LSB`), tornando o segundo `for` necessário para fazer a inversão dessa string.

**BINÁRIO PARA DECIMAL**

[image: metodo]

**Implementação:**

```
#include <string.h>

int bin2dec( const char * bin )
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int nbits = strlen(bin);

    for( i = 0; i < nbits; i++ )
        n += ( bin[ nbits - i - 1 ] == '1' ) ? (1 << i) : 0;

    return n;
}
```

**Explicação:**

A string contendo a representação binária do valor `bin` é varrida do final para o começo, o que corresponde a uma leitura que se inicia do bit menos significativo (`LSB`) para o mais significativo (`MSB`);

O acumulador `n` é responsável por armazenar o somatório das potências de base 2, que tem seu expoente calculado com base na significância de cada bit varrido que estiver setado.

**Testando Tudo:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define swap( a, b )   do{ int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; }while(0)


int bin2dec( const char * bin )
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int nbits = strlen(bin);

    for( i = 0; i < nbits; i++ )
        n += ( bin[ nbits - i - 1 ] == '1' ) ? (1 << i) : 0;

    return n;
}


const char * dec2bin( char * bin, int d )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for( i = 0; d > 0; d /= 2, i++ )
        bin[i] = (d % 2) ? '1' : '0';

    for( j = 0; j < (i / 2); j++ )
        swap( bin[j], bin[ i - j - 1 ] );

    bin[i] = '\0';

    return bin;
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    char bin[10] = {0};

    printf( "%dd = %sb\n", 53, dec2bin( bin, 53 ) );
    printf( "%dd = %sb\n", 85, dec2bin( bin, 85 ) );
    printf( "%dd = %sb\n", 128, dec2bin( bin, 128 ) );
    printf( "%dd = %sb\n", 15, dec2bin( bin, 15 ) );
    printf( "%dd = %sb\n", 255, dec2bin( bin, 255 ) );
    printf( "\n" );

    char a[] = "110101";
    char b[] = "1010101";
    char c[] = "10000000";
    char d[] = "1111";
    char e[] = "11111111";

    printf( "%sb = %dd\n", a, bin2dec(a) );
    printf( "%sb = %dd\n", b, bin2dec(b) );
    printf( "%sb = %dd\n", c, bin2dec(c) );
    printf( "%sb = %dd\n", d, bin2dec(d) );
    printf( "%sb = %dd\n", e, bin2dec(e) );

    return 0;
}
```

**Saída:**

```
53d = 110101b
85d = 1010101b
128d = 10000000b
15d = 1111b
255d = 11111111b

110101b = 53d
1010101b = 85d
10000000b = 128d
1111b = 15d
11111111b = 255d
```

Comment: aprecio a sua tentativa em ajudar, porém ainda estou tentando implementar a conversão dos decimais em binário usando o algoritmo que apresentei acima. Acho que vou criar uma outra pergunta com o algoritmo que estou usando, já apresentando um esboço do que fiz e com as minhas dúvidas.

Comment: @Mike Vide edição

Comment: agradeço o seu tempo dedicado aqui, porém vejo que no exemplo `1111b = 15d` ele não retorna os 4`0`s antes dos `1`s. E em alguns outros exemplos mais tem situações parecidas. Vou tentar outras maneiras de seguir adiante com a minha tarefa.   Obrigado! ;)