# Conversão decimal em binário na linguagem C usando a tabela ASCII

Tags: c, conversão, binary, ascii, decimal

Tenho que fazer um programa que faça a leitura de alguns caracteres e "transforme" cada caractere no número correspondente dele na tabela ASCII e depois transforme esse numero em binário e armazene em um vetor. Meu código até agora é:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
int i;
char mensagem[200];
    printf("Digite a mensagem: ");
        setbuf(stdin, NULL); // limpando o buffer antes de digitar a msg
        fgets(mensagem, 200, stdin); // leitura OK

int tamanho = strlen(mensagem); // pega a quant de caracteres (incluindo '\n')
// vetor de inteiros p/ armazenar os valores correspondentes dos caracteres na tabela ASCII
char *num_corresp_int; 
/* aloca um vetor de inteiros p/ os num correspondentes dos caracteres*/
    num_corresp_int =  malloc((tamanho) * sizeof(char)); 
        
    for(i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
        num_corresp_int[i] = mensagem[i]; // não está passando o '\0'
    }

char *vetor_binario; // aloca um vetor p/ armazenar os valores em binario
/* char pq preciso de apenas 1 byte p/ representar os números 0 e 1*/
    vetor_binario = malloc((tamanho) * sizeof(char)); 
        
int r;
/* (tamanho * 8) pq alocacarei um bit em cada posicao do vetor_binario*/
int a, j, aux = tamanho * 8; 
    for(i = 7, a = 0, j = 0; i >= 0 && j < aux; j++, i--) {
        r = num_corresp_int[a] >> i;
            if(r & 1) {
                vetor_binario[j] = 1;
            } else {
                vetor_binario[j] = 0;
            }
        if(i == 0){
            a++;
            i = 7;
        }else if(a == tamanho){
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < aux; i++){ // Testar se o armazenamento está sendo feito corretamente
        printf("%d", vetor_binario[i]); 
    }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Então a minha dúvida é sobre como definir a condição de parada total no laço:

```
for(i = 7, a = 0, j = 0; i >= 0 && j < aux; j++, i--) {
        r = num_corresp_int[a] >> i;
            if(r & 1) {
                vetor_binario[j] = 1;
            } else {
                vetor_binario[j] = 0;
            }
        if(i == 0){
            a++;
            i = 7;
        }else if(a == tamanho){
            break;
        }
}
```

Onde a **parada total do laço** (`break`) acontecerá quando `a`, que é usado para chegar até o `tamanho` da mensagem, for igual a `tamanho`. Acho que essa parada total deve ser parecida com o que esbocei usando `if` e `else if`.

Exemplo: Se for digitado `A` e `B` no teclado, o vetor `num_corresp_int[0] = 65` e `num_corresp_int[1] = 66`. E assim, o `vetor_binario` da posição `[0]`a `[7]`deverá armazenar os seguintes números correspondentes da tabela ASCII: `01000001` e, da posição `[8]`a `[15]` os seguintes números: `01000010`. Ou seja, a cada 8 posições do `vetor_binario` teremos juntos (**sequencialmente**) a **representação binária** de um número decimal da **tabela ASCII entre 0 e 255**.

Saída do programa agora se for digitado `AB` no teclado:

> 010000011000010000101000

Vejamos: Com a saída acima, além de outras que testei, vi que o programa armazena os 8 bits do primeiro caractere (`A`) corretamente, porém já p/ o segundo caractere (`B`) e posteriores, o `vetor_binario` não armazena o 1º bit dos caracteres, só do 2º bit em diante. **OBS:** nesse exemplo dado, os bits depois último bit do caractere `B` são correspondentes ao `\n`, sendo os dois últimos bits (`00`) restos que ainda não sei como tirar.

## Dúvidas

- Como definir a condição de parada total no laço?
- Como resolver o problema, em que a partir do 2º caractere, o 1º bit não estar sendo armazenado, e dos últimos bits excedentes?

Comment: Complexa a sua pergunta, seu código está estranho também.. Não sei qual o seu grau de conhecimento da linguagem, mas sugiro que tente utilizar algoritmos diferentes.. dois pontos importantes são: 1- Por que você está fazendo tudo na main? estruture seu código da maneira correta. 2- Por que utilizar vetor? considere a possibilidade de utilizar linkedList, struct e sobre o ponto de parada, para definir algo mais legível e fácil, talvez o uso de Recursividade. Como você mesmo disse, é iniciante... então procure aderir boas práticas desde o inicio da sua jornada. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Parece com [outra pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216128/64969). Certeza absoluta que não é duplicata? Ou a existência desta pergunta nova na verdade não seria uma clarificação da anterior?

Comment: Jefferson, essa nova pergunta é quase igual a anterior, porém aqui é adicionado o meu código e o meu problema a resolver é bem maior. Por isso resolvi abrir essa nova pergunta.

Comment: Sua motivação parece justa =], mas ainda assim prefiro me abster de qualquer decisão

Comment: O que é esta variável `a`? Tem um enunciado? Tem muita redundância e confusão aí. É tão mais simples fazer isso. Precisa mesmo usar um só laço, como 2 parece ficar mais simples. Tem algum motivo para usar um *array*  para armazenar, ou só usou porque foi a forma que penso u nisso?

Comment: @bigown 1º: a variável `a` é usada para chegar até o tamanho da mensagem inserida no teclado. Ou seja, é ela que será a condição de parada total do laço. 2º: A pergunta que faço é apenas uma pequena parte do enunciado com várias outras coisas a serem resolvidas. 3º: Só pensei em usar um `for`, senão acho que uma outra solução seria usar uma `função` p/ a conversão. 4º: Estou usando um array p/ armazenar os bits pois adiante precisarei de usar cada um desses bits guardados p/ passar p/ um arquivo.

Comment: É que o código está extramente confuso, fica difícil ajudar algo assim. poque ou você isola totalmente e mostra o que precisa. Se isolar é prova´vel que você mesmo ache o erro, se não fizer isso eu darei uma solução que não te servirá porque tem outras coisas omitidas na pergunta. 2 `for` é muito mais simples. Função nada tem a ver com isso, embora uma seria útil para organizar melhor o código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código é confuso, faz muita coisa desnecessária. A pergunta é extensa, mas pouca informação útil. Um dos motivos de ter dificuldade é o código ser complexo demais. Nem os mais experientes se viram bem com código complicado. Eu faria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char mensagem[200];
    printf("Digite a mensagem: ");
    fgets(mensagem, 200, stdin);
    mensagem[strcspn(mensagem, "\n")] = 0;
    int tamanho = strlen(mensagem);
    char vetor_binario[tamanho * 8 + 1];
    vetor_binario[tamanho * 8 + 1] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) vetor_binario[i * 8 + (7 - j)] = ((mensagem[i] >> j) & 1) + '0';
    }
    printf("%s", vetor_binario);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/CvF97x). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vptuggrx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/BinaryRepresentation.c).

Comment: É isso mesmo. Como sou iniciante em programação, quando estruturo meus códigos vou fazendo em partes, por isso ele estava extenso. Vejo que terei que estudar muito ainda para melhorar isso, inclusive na otimização de código.