# Não acha uma string dentro da outra

Tags: c, string

Ao executar esse código, e realizar um teste com:

```
Entrada: analise padrão
Mensagem: ana
```

Não é encontrado a frase dentro da outra.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){

char padrao [52], mensagem[52];
int aux=0;
printf("Digite uma palavra:");
fgest (mensagem,52,stdin);

printf("Digite o padrao a ser encontrado:");
fgets (padrao,52,stdin);

printf ("Palavra digitada: %s", mensagem);
printf ("Padrao digitado: %s", padrao);


while(strstr(mensagem, padrao)){
          aux++; // se for verdadeiro, acrescenta em aux
                     printf("aux: %d\n", aux); //verificação
          break;

          }

if (aux > 0){
                printf("****Padrao encontrado em %d mensagens!****", aux);
                }else {
                    printf("****Padrao nao encontrado!****");

                }
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Note que a função fgets interrompe a leitura quando detecta um caractere nova linha ('\n'), contudo este caractere fará parte da string lida. Exiba o comprimento da string padrao para se certificar. Uma solução é você substituir o caractere '\n' pelo caractere '\0' que indica o final da string. Provavelmente seu programa funcionaria para o padrão ise.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Troquei a função FGETS pela GETS e deu certo.

Comment: Pode ter dado certo mas não é a opção recomendável.

Comment: Evite `gets()`, é obsoleta. Pode substituir com `padrao[strlen(padrao) - 1]=0;` strlen também conta `'\n'` como um caractere qualquer.

Comment: @JuanSantos A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

O problema principal é de algoritmo mesmo. O laço não faz o menor sentido na forma escrita. Também tem erro de sintaxe no código e por isso não compila e está mal organizado. Fiz uma mudança para `scanf()` só para rodar. O `fgets()` tem um jeito próprio de montar o dado, mas este é [outro assunto colateral à pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43001/101) ([exemplo como fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216450/101)), depois pode consertar isso no seu código. Mas não use o `gets()` (a solução que se usa no `fgets()` é ruim pra performance, mas é o que tem pronto).

O laço não contava nada, ele saia na primeira execução, e na verdade se não saísse faria repetição infinita porque nada incrementava-o.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    char padrao[52], mensagem[52];
    printf("Digite uma palavra:");
    fgets(mensagem, 51, stdin);
    printf("Digite o padrao a ser encontrado:");
    scanf("%s", padrao);
    printf("Palavra digitada: %s", mensagem);
    printf("Padrao digitado: %s", padrao);
    int aux = 0;
    char *tmp = mensagem;
    while ((tmp = strstr(tmp, padrao))) {
        aux++;
        tmp++;
    }
    if (aux > 0) printf("****Padrao encontrado %d vezes!****", aux);
    else printf("****Padrao nao encontrado!****");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/stX3AW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CountOccurrences). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CountOccurrences.c).