# Qual a maneira mais comum de armazenar tamanho e capacidade de um "array dinamico" no C?

Tags: c, array, memória, estrutura-de-dados, alocação

No C, quando usamos alocação dinâmica, temos apenas um ponteiro, por exemplo:

```
array = (uint8_t *) malloc(100)
```

A questão é que isso não revela quantos itens tem no *array*, e nem qual o tamanho do *array*, portanto considere que:

```
array = (uint8_t *) malloc(100);
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
```

Em outras linguagens, como no Golang, seria possível fazer: `len(array)` e `cap(array)`, afim de saber quantos itens tem e qual o tamanho máximo (afim de evitar realocações). No Zig, temos o `len` que seria `100`, o que já é menos pior.

Entretanto, no C, aparentemente não tem isso, então pensei em fazer algo como:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t * Data;
    uint32_t _len;
    uint32_t _cap;
} DataArray;
```

Dessa forma, a estrutura acima seria, `_len = 2` e `_cap = 100`. Isto é, inclusive, como o Slice do Golang funciona. Uma prática similar ocorre no Zig, onde um slice possui um tamanho e um ponteiro.

---

A questão é: essa é a forma mais comum e adequada de ser feita no C? Existe outra forma de fazer isso e que é mais tradicional de ser feito no C? Existe alguma biblioteca padrão que adicione alguma estrutura similar?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123208/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285379/101

Comment: Essa que descreveu é uma maneira comum, criando uma estrutura que contem o ponteiro, algum limite e a capacidade em uso. Não é incomum usar também um valor com a capacidade inicial e outro com o tamanho de um bloco de expansão. Não é incomum usar também um ponteiro para o ponteiro para o dado, a la `main`. E o endereço de uma estrutura dessas é passado como parâmetro, evitando assim passar o tamanho. Esse é o conceito de encapsulamento.

Comment: A título de curiosidade, em slices, Rust armazena somente o ponteiro e o comprimento (já que slices não permitem expansão). Quando tipos podem crescer, como `String` ou `Vec`, Rust também armazena a tripla de ponteiro, comprimento e capacidade. Eu acho que é realmente bastante comum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depende do contexto e necessidade.

Se vai usar só dentro de uma função então não tem muito o que pensar, tá tudo ali o que precisa.

Quando passa de uma função para outra o que vejo sendo mais comum é fazer isso passando junto um outro parâmetro com o tamanho, inclusive as funções padrões seguras de C operam assim. Eu prefiro a outra forma a seguir sempre que possível e viável.

Essa forma é a adotada na pergunta, com variações, inclusive o AP já sabe que é assim internamente em Go, Zig e praticamente qualquer linguagem, até quando isso é feito em uma classe. C apenas não tem isso pronto, ela deixa você fazer como achar melhor para a sua necessidade. Mas não tem muito o que inventar.

C deixa, por exemplo, fazer o que ela faz com *string*, e se quiser saber o tamanho deve contar até achar um elemento que indica que não tem mais dados ali. Uma decisão extremamente infeliz que pagamos caro até hoje em tudo (não detalharei porque não é o foco).

Eu adotaria a postada se não tiver algum outro impedimento. Talvez em algum caso tamanho e capacidade fundidos, criando uma limitação, claro.

A dificuldade é interagir com bibliotecas que não esperam essa informação assim, incluindo a padrão, nada grave, só não é tão conveniente.

O duro é que cada biblioteca pode usar de um jeito. Se vai conversar com o Windows por exemplo tem de tudo quanto é jeito e você tem que se adaptar.

Acho que não precisa dizer que qualquer forma sempre exigirá que chame funções manualmente para manter esses dados consistentes e sincronizados.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você teria alguma referência para eu entender qual foi a decisão infeliz a qual pagamos caro até hoje?

Comment: Acho que pode ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101, daí pode pesquisar mais detalhes. Fora isso, só postando uma pergunta específica.